# See cursor function info in NetBeans

Tags: php, netbeans, code-completion

There is any way to see the function auto completion code? For example:

```
$a = test("cat", false, false, false, true, true, false, true);
```

In PhpDesigner if I put the mouse over the third "FALSE" I see the auto completion code and the variable name defined in the method declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution! :D

`Control + P` over the parameter

More info here: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/editor-codereference.html#parameters

Answer (score 3):

Keep the CONTROL key pressed and hover over the function name and you get something like this:

[image]

Not exactly what you asked for but i am not aware of another way to do this right now. Nice question, didn't know i want that feature until now ;)

Comment: Mmmmmm, the function must be documented :(

In phpDesigner you can see the variable name, I really need that xD

Comment: Mmmm, afraid i am out of ideas then :( Even so i'd like to have that feature now ;)

Comment: Well, i'm going to put this as correct, but I still need that feature xD I'll try request it or to make a plugin to get it.

Comment: Control + P over the parameter! http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/editor-codereference.html#parameters